# What are the Firefly specifications?

Tags: firefly, spaceship, tv, joss-whedon

Are there any canonical specifications for the Firefly ship?

Including (but not limited to):

- Speed
- Cargo capacity

Comment: Do you mean "canon specifications"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's a great article at [The Cortex](http://www.vfocus.com/cortex/?q=node/12), which in turn, got it from the [Firefly/Serenity Wiki](http://firefly.wikia.com/wiki/Firefly-class_transport_ship). The basic specs are at the bottom:

```
              Cost in            Crew/   Cargo   Sick  Shuttle   Carry
Name          Karmans  Speed     Pass    Tons    Bay?    Bay?    MULE?
Firefly        5250      Med      10      400    Yes    Yes (x2)  Yes
Size: Medium
```

The acceleration is 5.5 G, pretty decent if you ask me.